# Windows Forms in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 doesn't have Win 8 Style

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a Win7 machine which I installed MVS2013. I'm trying to do a simple Windows Form Application, but it doesn't have the Win 8 style, but the Win 7.
How could I make one which looks like the Win 8 style?
Or, am I doing it right? Because I've heard that Win 8 only work with Apps.

Thanks for your time.
Best regards.

Comment: *Because I've heard that Win 8 only work with Apps.* Yeah, it's an Operating System...

Comment: Win 8 metro style i think you cannot create in a win7 environment. I think you need win8.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Form Application is what it says and it has outdated look (doesn't even completely keep up with Vista style as it is old technology used on XP, WPF application is the way Windows Vista and above work).

For Windows 8 you must use Windows Store Application project, which can be only launched if you have Visual Studio 2012 or above on Windows 8 or above.